# What does the title "Gone in 60 Seconds" mean?

Tags: title, gone-in-60-seconds

What is the reason for the movie title *Gone in 60 Seconds*? I could not find any explicit reference to the title during the movie. I expected a 60-second car theft or something like that.

Comment: I always thought that it was referencing how long it took to steal a car.

Comment: @steelersquirrel Is it common knowledge that a car takes 60 seconds to steal? I never heard of it before the movie

Comment: I don't know.  That's why I only posted a comment.  I have no sources to back up that claim.  I guess you can refer to the two answers that are posted so far.  They seem to be claiming the same thing.  I have never stolen a car before, so I wouldn't know ;)

Comment: I recall, maybe 30 years ago, seeing on TV (one of the lawyer dramas, I'm thinking) a demonstration of stealing a car.  The "thief" used a "slide hammer" to extract the door lock and the ignition lock, then a screwdriver to start the car.  It took, probably, 20 seconds.  Likely 60 seconds is a good "upper limit" on the time, given that things might not go perfectly right.  And, of course, modern cars have electronic ignition lockouts, so significantly more effort would be required, as the car would have to be effectively "hot wired".

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## The title is referring to cars and the time it takes to steal one.

The original movie's cover is:

[image: Gone in 60 Seconds cover]

As it says:

> You can lock your car, but if [Maindrian Pace] wants it... it's **Gone in 60 Seconds**

The 2000 remake takes the same title and overall plot.

As [Sudip Biswas](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/47070/sudip-biswas) pointed out, there is also a sign in the movie that reads:

> If you leave your car unlocked it will be Gone in 60 Seconds

which reinforces the overall idea.

Comment: Oh...nice find with the original movie poster with that quote!

Comment: Cool poster. So, I guess it's just a nice sounding quote that someone came up with right? I mean, there's no relation to the actual movie plot. It could be "Gone in 2 minutes" or "Gone in 30 seconds". 60 seconds just happened to sound better, regardless of whatever happens in the movie

Comment: I think *60 seconds* is just meant to represent a short amount of time, yes, but I can't be sure about that

Comment: Wow. I did not even know the remake, **was** a remake.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner - Personally, I don't think you were missing anything. The Nick Cage version is far superior in my opinion.

Answer (score 18):

[Source IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187078/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv)

> When Mirror Man is talking to the clerk at the police impound yard, a sign can be seen in the background that reads "**If you leave your car unlocked it will be Gone in 60 Seconds** (1974)". This same sign was used in the original 1974 version of the movie.

I believe this is the true inspiration for the movie's title. It's evident that [the 2000 movie takes its title from the 1974 one](http://www.avclub.com/review/gone-in-60-seconds-20005) and the origin of the 1974 title is actually that catch phrase that was shared by the second answer.

> Bruckheimer's latest, Gone In 60 Seconds, takes its title, basic premise, and a few gags from a 1974 exploitation film of the same name by used-car dealer turned actor-director H.B. Halicki.

Comment: Do you have a source to back up your belief that this was the true inspiration for the movie's title?

Comment: I agree with this. It's the time it takes to boost a car. Never occurred to me it could be anything else O.o

Comment: @steelersquirrel You think it might be a coincidence that there's a sign with a phrase referring to how long it takes to steal a car and that exact same phrase being the title of the movie about stealing cars?

Comment: @SteveIves I am not saying that it's not a coincidence.  I am just saying that when a question is answered, it should have sources to back it up.  That's great that the OP believes that this is the true inspiration.  It would be great to show some effort in answering the question by providing some sort of source for this belief rather than posting a blurb off of the IMDb trivia section.

Comment: @steelersquirrel..Actually this ques did baffle me for sometime now, and it went out of my head lately. I saw this question and tried helping the user with some reference. I did my searches but couldn't find anyone actually vouching for this or saying this reason in an interview or something.

Comment: I agree.  I looked for some type of source as well when I first saw this question and couldn't find one.  I always guessed that's what the title meant, but I don't have any evidence backing it up :)